# How to fix 'com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException' when using C3P0

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, c3p0, timeoutexception

I used c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar. The Database is Vertica.
There are up to 12 concurrent threads. So i set minPoolSize to 12, maxPoolSize to 24, and initialPoolSize to 12.
I have a connection problem. Mosttime time it works fine, but sometime it does not. This is the error :

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        ...
        at com.cmb.mr.mc.scheduler.ScheduledTasks.largePoolTask(ScheduledTasks.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:515)
        ...
    ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 27 more
    Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@3956dfb1 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 30 more
```

---

The Configuration:

```
    <bean id="dataSourceP" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver" />

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:vertica://${Url}/${Db}" />
    <property name="user" value="${User}" />
    <property name="password" value="${Password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="600"/>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="24"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="12"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="60"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSourceP"/>
</bean>
```

can you please give some hint on how to solve this?

Comment: I get your try to checkout connections more than maxPoolSize. Check if you release connections (via connection.close()) after you use them.

Comment: @alpert I think the c3p0 will help me manage the connection so I did not close the connection in my code. I use jdbcTemplate.query to acquire data. However I once found the sessions I queried in the Vertica was  more than the maxPoolSize.

Comment: when you close a connection what really happens is you give that connection back to the pool, c3p0 manages that. If you do not close and give connections back to the pool you will be out of connections which seems as the case in your problem.